# Java Formatter class %c %C conversion on console

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-16, formatter

As per Oracle's official documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html
the %c or %C operator should be printing a Unnicode Character. But, code simulation like this,

```
System.out.format("%1$c", 97);
```

yields the character 'a', which is as per ASCII value. Any value greater than 255 results in '?'

**EDIT**
Can you print a Unicode character by any other way (like on the console)?

The closest I could get is by explicity passing Character-set to an OutputStream

```
char[] toWirte = {913,914,915,916};
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"));
out.write(new String(toWirte).getBytes("UTF-16"));
```

I guess, Writer implementations implicitly assume UTF-8 as charcter-set.

**Does anyone know of any other way.**

Comment: For the codes 0-127, Unicode and ASCII are identical.

Comment: This is not a bug, and Oracle did not make a mistake; you just misunderstand how it works. Don't bother reporting this to Oracle.

Comment: Most likely because the console window in which you are printing the result does not support the characters you are trying to print.

Comment: Tried output through console and file apart from IDE. Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Unicode code chart:

> http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Decimal 97 is hexadecimal 61 which is defined as character 'a'.  As noted in a comment, code points 0 through 127 (00 through 7F) are defined the same in Unicode as ASCII.  This is intentional for compatibility and easier migration.